# Error on viewing records

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

i followed this tutorial: http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2016/09/aspnet-web-api-and-sql-server.html. I've deployed it to iis by following this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwwvNft38Us and it works initially with the url : http://localhost/WebApplication10. However when trying to access http://localhost/WebApplication10/api/users, instead of giving a list of users it gives the following error:

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open.

here's my code for the UserController where the error pops up:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using UserDataAccess;

namespace WebApplication10.Controllers
{
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
public IEnumerable<User> Get()
{
    using (UsersDBEntities entities = new UsersDBEntities())
    {
        return entities.Users.ToList();
    }
}

public User Get(string name)
{
    using (UsersDBEntities entities = new UsersDBEntities())
    {
        return entities.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == name);
    }
}
}
}
```

and here's the code for the web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="UsersDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/UserDataModel.csdl|res://*/UserDataModel.ssdl|res://*/UserDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=BPS-DEV-M001;initial catalog=UsersDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: Is your SQL server is running?

Comment: yes it's running

Comment: Do you have an access to your SQL Server according to your user/password used.

Comment: yes i have access

Comment: Is Sql Server  Installed in separate PC?

Comment: no it's installed on the same pc for development

Comment: Did you open the database before it goes on that code?

Answer (score 1):

Open Database like this?

```
using (DatabaseEntities DBEntities = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    DBEntities.Connection.Open();
    // Follow your code here.....
}
```